# Disable Log::info in production using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, monolog

I assumed that by default the Log::info calls wouldn't log in production, but they are still coming in.

Im setting production using my .env file

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
```

Ive tried these commands as well, but no luck

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: I don't think Logging is associated with the environment. If it's production or not, laravel will log all information.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want logging in production?

Comment: To Speed up the task, i only want Log::error logs to be reported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I think that it's too late to search for all the `Log::info()` and do the proposed answer by @jon__o

```
if (App::environment('local', 'staging')) {
    Log::info($error);
}
```

But you can still do something. You can override the default Laravel logger instance with your own implementation.

Go to your `ApplicationServiceProvider` and override the `log` instance with a custom one:

```
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->registerLogger();
}

/**
 * Register the logger instance in the container.
 *
 * @return MyCustomWriter
 */
protected function registerLogger()
{
    $this->app->instance('log', $log = new MyCustomWriter(
        new Monolog($this->app->environment()), $app['events'])
    );

    $log->dontLogInfoOnEnvironmnets(['production', 'staging', 'other']);
    return $log;
}
```

Now you can create your custom writer by just extending the Laravel's `Writer` and overriding the `info()` method.

```
class MyCustomWriter extends \Illuminate\Log\Writer
{

    protected $dontInfoOn = [];

    /**
     * Log an informational message to the logs.
     *
     * @param  string  $message
     * @param  array  $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function info($message, array $context = [])
    {
        // Since we are providing the app environment to the Monolog instance in out ApplicationServiceProvider
        // we can get the environment from the Monolog getName() method
        if(!in_array($this->monolog->getName(), $this->dontInfoOn)) {
            return parent::info($message, $context);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Don't log info() on the supplied environments .
     *
     * @param  array  $environments
     * @return void
     */
    public function dontLogInfoOnEnvironmnets(array $environments)
    {
        $this->dontInfoOn = $environments;
    }
}
```

This way, you can still keep you `Log::info` on testing environments without checking every time.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone still finding this thread (8 years later):

Configure your log channels in config/logging.php file

Set "level" parameter for your log channel to a .env variable

Example:

```
  'channels' => [
    'slack' => [
      'driver' => 'slack',
      'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
      'username' => 'Lumen Log',
      'emoji' => ':boom:',
      'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'error'),
    ]
  ]
```

Now you can set the LOG_LEVEL variable in your .env file for each environment

Answer (score 1):

Only the displaying of errors will be suppressed when your application is not in debug mode.  The Log::info() function will always log when called.

The simple solution is for you to wrap that Log::info() function in something like this:

```
if (App::environment('local', 'staging')) {
    Log::info($error);
}
```

Be sure to include the App facade `use App;` at the top of your file.  Alternatively you can use the app() helper to get the environment: `$environment = app()->environment();`.

Comment: Ive got Log::info statements everywhere, is there a single place i can do it?

Comment: Yeah you can extend the log writers like @Blue Genie suggested.  There may be other ways too.  If you are using a PHP editor like Sublime, you can Find and Replace in files across your entire app directory.   This answer I posted is my suggestion because it's a good practice to use the environment to your advantage in your day-to-day coding.